# Stuck inside a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I created a Heads and Tails program that is stuck inside a choice option.
It was supposed to break if 'y' or 'n' is selected, but it stills asks to press y to continue or n to skip.

The logic appears to be fine. Anyone could give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

```
import random 
resp = 'y'
while resp == 'y':
 n = random.randint(0,1)
 if n == 0:
    print('HEADS')
 else:
    print('TAILS')
 resp = str(input("Press y to continue or n to skip )).lower()
  while resp != 'y' or resp != 'n':
     resp = str(input("Press y to continue or n to skip ")).lower()
  if resp == 'n':
     break
```

Comment: For *any* value of `resp`, given that it must be a `str`, either `resp != 'y'` or `resp != 'n'` - there's no way logically to break that loop.

Comment: Side note: There's absolutely no need to cast the result of ``input`` to str - unless you have to write Python 2 compatible code.

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code. First, which I believe is just a copy-paste error: you're missing a closing quotation mark in the prompt in the first `input()` call. Second, you don't need to cast `input()` to `str`, as it already returns a `str`. Third, and most importantly, as @jonrsharpe mentioned, your logic for breaking out of the input validation loop is flawed.

Comment: The `if resp == 'n':` is not within the `while` loop

Comment: Thank you all. I figured out that the str casting was need to call the lower function. Yes you are right about the loop issue. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard codiing follows ***DRY*** code. That is `DO NOT REPEAT` yourself.

Looks Like your code has too much repetitive work.

Also, no need to convert response to string since input function converts everything into string,

```
resp = str(input("Press y to continue or n to skip )).lower()
```

Correct indentation, It should be `4 spaces`.

```
import random
while True:
     resp = input("Press y to continue or n to skip : " ).lower()
     if resp == 'n':
        break
     n = random.randint(0,1)
     if n == 0:
        print('HEADS')
     else:
        print('TAILS')
```

Comment: What's with the inconsistent indentation increments? I realize that's how OP did it, but you should correct that and point it out.

Comment: Also, you don't need to cast `input()` to `str` in Python 3.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of, there is a quote missing here:

```
str(input("Press y to continue or n to skip )).lower()
```

If I input y, then `resp != n` will be true, if I input n, `resp != y` will be true. So it will just loop as long as I enter y or n.

```
while resp != 'y' or resp != 'n':
```

So it should be:

```
while resp != 'y' and resp != 'n':
```

Comment: Thank you. It really worked and I also fixed the str cast issue.